# How to write a nested test case like Jasmine in Python

Tags: python, unit-testing

Jasmine can write a nested test case like this:

```js
  describe('func1', () => {
    it('case1', () => {

    })
    it('case2', () => {

    })
  })
  describe('func2', () => {
    it('case1', () => {

    })
    it('case2', () => {

    })
  })
```

I'd like to write the same in Python.
I can't find it in WWW.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Starting from Python 3.4 you may create subtests in your `unittest` test cases classes (of course, if you use the standard `unittest` library for testing):

```py
class MyTestCase(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_func1(self):
        with self.subTest('case1'):
            ...

        with self.subTest('case2'):
            ...

    def test_func2(self):
        with self.subTest('case1'):
            ...

        with self.subTest('case2'):
            ...
```

**MORE:** https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.html#distinguishing-test-iterations-using-subtests

Comment: Thanks a lot. Tomorrow I'll try this answer can realize I want   to do.

Comment: Your answer can realize I want to do. I read your reference, I have misunderstanded subTest is only for iteration test.

Comment: This should not be the accepted answer, because one failed subtest prevents all other subtests to not run.

Comment: @DarkTrick This is not true. It depends on how you run a test suite: until the first failure or until the last test/subtest. Subtests are not different to normal test functions in terms of execution.

Comment: @VisioN valuable information! :) Can you put that information in the answer + the way you need to run it to not stop?

Comment: @DarkTrick It's not directly related to the question. Should be enough to keep in the comments section.